# Do I need mass to calculate the rms speed of diatomic Nitrogen?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, ideal-gas

Calculate the rms speed of diatomic Nitrogen ($N_2$) at an altitude of $600$ km, where the temperature is $1500$ K.

I'm confused because only an altitude and a temperature is given, and  I feel like I need the mass if the Nitrogen to complete the problem.

$v_{rms} = \sqrt{\frac{3K_bT}{m}}$

Comment: Hint: Atomic mass of Nitrogen is 14

Comment: Would I take the atomic mass and multiply by two? Since the Nitrogen is diatomic.

Comment: Yes. Just substitute in your formula

Comment: Pointless edit, lol